# Does resolution of grid map influence localization precision?

Tags: navigation, ros-kinetic, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to know if resolution of grid map can influence precision of localization. Say, i have a map with 5cm resolution, will localization algorithm be limited to 5cm precision?  Will this depend on different algorithm such as ACML and other algorithms ?

About AMCL，i noticed the sensor models (BeamModel, LikelihoodFieldModel) implemented in ROS would limit particle's precision to the resolution of grid map. That implies me that the whole ACML algorithm implemented in ROS would never reach a better precision than the resolution of grid map.

I am new to localization algorithm, so i don't know if i am right.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/315826/does-resolution-of-grid-map--influence-localization-precision?/) by [huchaohong](https://answers.ros.org/users/40059/huchaohong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2019-02-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, it does.

It is like that you are using a ruler with bigger intervals you cannot measure precisely. Grid is like the divisions when you localize.

However, using particle filter algorithm you may get a quite precise result with large covariace, means you will not know that you get a precise reading, the belief is low.

---

Originally posted by [tianb03](https://answers.ros.org/users/1587/tianb03/) with karma: 710 on 2019-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1